# regression test for command line program in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, linux, unit-testing, testing

I have a linux utility that parses structured input ( a text file ), processes it and prints the result to the screen. For example: (input)

```
COMMAND=create
    NAME=Stack
    SURNAME=Overflow
```

My utility takes as input the above text file and tries to create an object (stack, overflow) in the database. If the action is executed successfully my program returns something like this:

```
COMMAND=create
    Code=0
    Result=OK
```

or in case of error

> ```
> COMMAND=create
>     Code=10
>     Result=Duplicate entry
> ```

I am looking for a good way to create a regression suite for my binary. Any ideas that fit my case? Is any alternative to JUnit in C/C++?

Comment: C or C++? The answers will be different. "C/C++" is not a language.

Comment: Some binaries are pure C. However most of them are C++. My basic target is C++.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Choosing a C++ unit testing tool/framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699/choosing-a-c-unit-testing-tool-framework)

Comment: For C unit testing, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/2745775/10077.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google test is an awesome C++ framework, but it has a bit of a learning curve: https://github.com/google/googletest/

Answer (score 1):

I recommend CTest, which is part of CMake.  It's pretty easy to configure and adding a test is as as simple as creating a test executable and calling TEST("Code should be 0", Code=0, true);  Or something similar ... and it works for both c and c++ ;)